# why images not coming for UIBarButton item of navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Here is my code. This is adding image but images are being appeared in navigation bar.

```
UIToolbar* toolbartop = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 45)];
[toolbar setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

// create an array for the buttons
NSMutableArray* buttonstop = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];


UIBarButtonItem *remainderButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                    target:self 
                                    action:@selector(LoadOption:)];


 [buttonstop addObject:remainderButton];
[remainderButton release];

UIBarButtonItem *faveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(homeAction)];
[buttonstop addObject:faveButton];
[faveButton release];


// put the buttons in the toolbar and release them
[toolbartop setItems:buttonstop animated:NO];
[buttonstop release];

// place the toolbar into the navigation bar
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbartop];
```

But this code is showing image in navigation right bar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *settingButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(homeAction)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingButton;
```

Why left navigation bar button is not showing images?

```
[toolbartop release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the image to your left BarButtonItem as follows:

```
UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button1.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,105,30);
[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"image1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:appDelegate action:@selector(Open_Link1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button2.frame=CGRectMake(105,0,105,30);
[button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"image2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 addTarget:appDelegate action:@selector(Open_Link2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIView *viewButtons = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 210, 30)];
[viewButtons addSubview:button1];
[viewButtons addSubview:button2];
[button1 release];
[button2 release];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:viewButtons];
[viewButtons release];
```

Here please make sure that the methods "Open_Link1" and "Open_Link2" must exists in the code as follows:

```
-(void)Open_Link1
{
     // Write your logic
}

-(void)Open_Link2
{
     // Write your logic
}
```

Let me know if you want more help.

Comment: Thanks. But how to add 2 buttons there.

Comment: I have changed my answer. You can add 2 buttons now.

Comment: I am getting an exception in this line [viewButtons addSubView:button1];
 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604e8f0
2011-07-12 20:01:27.623 FavesApplication[5215:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView addSubView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604e8f0'

Comment: please never mind. :) Its my mistake. I am seeing navbar is blank no any buttons are being added. (not getting exception).

Comment: I again changed my answer. Please check and if you think it's your answer then you can do the needful.

Comment: Great. Let me know if you need more help for future.

Answer (score 0):

The left bar button item is automatically used by the framework for showing a "Back" button. You can't put anything here, at least not when your navigation bar is managed by a UINavigationController. For this to work you have to handle the UINavigationBar yourself.

Edit:
in your leftBarButtonItem, try putting a UISegmentedControl instead of a UIToolbar for toolbartop.

Comment: But it is adding buttons there except image is not appearing there.

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to add the files to your project's resources?

Comment: @Cyrille.. I am getting warning here [toolbartop setItems:buttonstop animated:NO];

Comment: You can create a custom leftbarbutton.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a button to toolbar but you aren't adding your toolbar to any view.  Try to set the button directly using

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonStop];
```

Comment: @Praveen.. I am getting an exception.

Comment: Thats cos the button is probably released. I will reply in sometime